# Expanding ExpandableListView from a very late asynchronous callback

Tags: android, asynchronous, expandablelistview

I hope I'm wording my question clearly.

I'm working on a legacy project and there's a particular screen that looks like this:
[image: Screen]

The big rectangle is a `Fragment` and the multiple rectangles are each an `ExpandableListFragment` inside a `ViewPager`

The content of each `ExpandableListFragment` is loaded via JSON from server.

- On each `ExpandableListFragment` I sent a request to server for JSON data inside its `onActivityCreated` after I have created and set the associated list adapter.
- This request is asynchronous and there's a callback to load the obtained data.
- The data thus displayed as ExpandableList with group at index (0) expanded.
- I could scroll `ViewPager` to left or right depending on the size of contained `ExpandableListFragment`
- I have figured out to sent a request for each `ExpandableListFragment` exactly one.
- But, suppose that I have gone so far to the left (or right) too quickly. For example, I'm at index number 12.
- And then request for index number 0 is finished, and my callback got called.
- I've got `IllegalStateException` Content view not yet created.
- The responsible line for the exception is, the method is the callback method.

  ```
  public void processResult(ScheduleListJSON response) {
    setListData(response);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // The problem line is here.
    getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(ProgramScheduleExpandableList.this);
    if (getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount() > 0) {
      getExpandableListView().expandGroup(0);
    }
  ```

  }
- I think it's because I have gone so far to the right that the listview addressed by my callback (index 0) in this method has already gone.

Question:
Any suggestion on how to achieve my intention? Expand a group view on response which could arrive very late that even if the user hasn't left the main Activity, it may have already gone because the fragment is so far off screen.

Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**
oh wait, does `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int)` has something to do with how many listviews inside a pager are guaranteed to be available?

Comment: you are probably better off doing some persistence with the expandable value and when the view comes on screen just check if it needs to expand

Comment: the contents are guaranteed to change per hour. But that's actually a great suggestion.